How do I solve this ODE? $\frac{1+2y'^2}{\sqrt{y(1+y'^2)}} = C$
$$\frac{1+2y'^2}{\sqrt{y(1+y'^2)}} = C$$
Can somebody help me solve this please?
Something of this form appears when trying to solve a generalized brachistochrone problem, where the particle no longer has to reach a certain point but rather a certain abscissa value. Here $y$ is a function of $x$ and $C$ is a constant.
I tried clearing the denominator and squaring both sides to get rid of the square root, but since I'm not dealing with a linear ODE I'm feeling a bit out classed. I tried a power series method but things got messy real quick so I abandoned ship can came here.
Thanks in advance!!

The solution, from software, will be the solution of a complicated elementary equation. Do you want to solve implicitly or explicitly for $y$?

I'm not seeing a dependent variable.  Did you try solving for y' in terms of y?

@Mike $y'$ stands here for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$

@user58697 Yes, but if you can get it in the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(y)$, then $\int\frac{dy}{f(y)}=x+C$

You can differentiate again wrt $x$ and get
$$\begin{aligned}\left(\dfrac{1+2y'^2}{\sqrt{y(1+y'^2)}}\right)'\overset{!}{=}0&\iff
\dfrac{y'(1+3y'^2+2y'^4-2yy'')}{[y(1+y'^2)]^{3/2}}=0\\
&\iff \left\{\begin{aligned}
&y'=0\iff y=\dfrac{1}{C^2}\\
&1+3y'^2+2y'^4-2yy''=0
\end{aligned}\right.\end{aligned}$$As for the second equation, you can parametrize $p(y)=y'\iff pp'=y''$ and obtain a separable differential equation:
$$1+3p^2+2p^4=2ypp'\iff \int\dfrac{2p\,\mathrm dp}{1+3p^2+2p^4}=\int\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{y}\iff y=K\frac{1+2p^2}{1+p^2}$$
Reverting to $y'$ and substituting $y$ in the original ODE we obtain
$$\sqrt{1+2y'^2}=C\sqrt K\iff y=\pm\frac{C^2K_1-1}{2}x+K_2$$
I think $y$ should only depend on one unknown up to boundary condition constant so the other should depend on $C$.
Alternatively, you could square both sides like you did and solve the $2$nd order equation in $y'^2$:
$$\begin{aligned}
(1+2y'^2)^2&=C^2y(1+y'^2)\\
4y'^4+(4-C^2y)y'^2+1-C^2y&=0
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus,
$$y'^2=\dfrac{C^2y-4\ \pm\sqrt{8C^2y+C^4y^2}}{8}\iff \displaystyle\int \dfrac{(\pm)_2 2\sqrt 2\,\mathrm dy}{\sqrt{C^2y-4\ (\pm)_1\sqrt{8C^2y+C^4y^2}}}=\int\mathrm dx$$

Out of these solutions I'd trust definetely the $y=1/C^2$ one (although we'd need to know the boundary conditions for $y'$ in order to verify if it can be $0$), and the last one too; not sure about the parametrized solution though...

Okay... I did something wrong in getting to the ODE i typed up.. I was supposed to get a cycloid >.<

So what the correct ode would be?

I thought it was suspicious too. In order to get the correct ODE we want to minimize the time integral:
$$t=\int\frac{\mathrm ds}{v}=\int\frac{\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}}{\sqrt{\dot  x^2+\dot y^2}},\mathrm dx\overset{\text{Cons. of energy}}{=}\int\sqrt{\frac{1+y'(x)^2}{2gy}},\mathrm dx$$
Thus, the lagrangian would be $\mathcal L (x,y,y'(x))=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+y'(x)^2}{2gy}}$.
Applying the E-L equation for $x$ we obtain the following ODE:
$$2yy''+y'^2+1=0$$
